# Are Shrimp, Lobster, Crayfish and Crab Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

Are Shrimp, Lobster, Crayfish and Crab Halal? Are they different from fiqh point of view?

Comment: Linked- [lobsters-and-crabs-halal-or-haram-due-to-boiling-alive](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5743/)

Answer (score 8):

From the point of view of Shia just Shrimp is halal.

See followings:

- http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa782
- http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa2070

Answer (score 6):

> Are Shrimp, Lobster, Crayfish and Crab Halal?

Yes, those are halaal:

> Hence all kinds of food from the sea are permissible, whether they are
>   plants or animals, alive or dead. Allaah says (interpretation of the
>   meaning): “Lawful to you is (the pursuit of) water-game and its use
>   for food – for the benefit of yourselves and those who travel…”
>   [al-Maa’idah 5:96]. Ibn ‘Abbaas said: “ Sayduhu (lit. hunting,
>   pursuit) refers to whatever is taken from it alive, and ta’aamuhu
>   (lit. its food) means whatever is taken dead.”

[Full fatwa here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/1919) which explains in more detail, which also explains if animals such as Crocodiles, Frogs, Otters and turtles are halaal or not, but to summaries the fatwa:

```
Crocodiles = Haraam 
Frogs = Haraam 
Sea Snakes = Halaal 
Otters and turtles = Halaal but only after slaughtering them in the islamic manner 
Any food which can cause you harm, even if it is from the sea is Haraam.
```

Comment: Otters can actually do a surprising amount of damage - is there a clear definition of "cause harm" for this?

Comment: In terms of harm, I think the fatwa means `harm` as in it being harmful to eat.

Comment: Ah, right. So blowfish (which, if not prepared correctly, can have lethal tetrodotoxin) would be haraam. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can't say for sure, but I would assume so based on that fatwa.

Comment: Blowfish should be fine if prepared correctly, as there would be no harm. If it was prepared incorrectly, it would be haram for sure.

Comment: @oshirowanen - I thought I remembered reading somewhere that the Hanafi school of jurisprudence had a more narrow view and holds that only fish are halal. Is this true?

Comment: I want to know if it is true that God Almighty Has forbid and declared as a major sin to eat what is carnivore like:carnivore see animal?Like:Sharks,Jellyfish,Blue Wale and etc?And other kinds of carnivore animals