# Is eating sushi halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, food

Rice of course is halal as far as I know, but what about of other seafood that can be used when cooking sushi such as shrimps, crabs, salmon, caviar etc?

Comment: see also this related question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2295/are-shrimp-lobster-crayfish-and-crab-halal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some ingreidents in Sushi that need investigation.

- Shellfish, such as shrimp and crab. Most Sunni schools of thought regard them as *halal*. However, many Hanafis regard them as *haram* or *makrooh*. While Jafari fiqh considers shrimp and prawn as *halal*, crab and non-scaled sea creatures (such as eel) are *haram*.
- [Mirin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirin) is a Japanese condiment that has low alcoholic content, and is sometimes used in making Sushi rice. So ask the Sushi chef if they are using it or not, and if they do use it ask if it's the alcoholic version.
- Meat is less commonly associated with Sushi, but it isn't unheard of. So of course pork and non-Zabiha meat is not *halal*.

Comment: I also recall reading that eel is considered haram by at least one of the major schools, but can't find any reliable sources thereof.  Prompted this related question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5736/which-school-considers-eel-haram-and-why

Comment: @goldPseudo - Really? I *love* eel :(

Comment: @SystemDown AFAIK the general view isn't that strict about eels.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to our site. You're asking a question that's both easy and difficult.

First, from the basics: *all food is halal until proven haram.* If there's something which you're not sure about, by default, you should consider it okay to eat. Most of the porhibitions are well-established in scripture (Qur'an and hadith), including:

- No meat that is not slaughtered Islamically ([2:173](http://quran.com/2/173))
- Pork and boar ([2:173](http://quran.com/2/173) again)
- Alcohol, in small or large quantities ([5:90](http://quran.com/5/90))

On the other hand, anything from the sea is okay to eat ([5:96](http://quran.com/5/96)).

These are the basic rulings that come into play with sushi. Whether food is permissible or not depends on these general maxims, as well as other, specific maxims, such as not eating predators, avoiding flambee, ingredients derived from animal sources that are not in super small quantities, etc.

I suggest some research, and finding out what's in the sushi -- looking at the ingredient list.

Comment: Not all scholars agree as to what all is considered permissible according to 5:96; in order to be useful, this post should specify which school(s) it represents (at least for the claim "*anything* from the sea..."), or explicitly account for the difference of opinion.

Comment: @goldPseudo that's beyond the scope of the question. Scholars talked about water predators, amphibians, etc. -- again, below the scope of this question.

Comment: Shellfish (e.g. crab) are well within the scope of the question, and are one of the categories in which the scholars differ.

Comment: @ashes999 goldPseudo is right when he says it would be better if you gave a more holistic answer which would then include how the main schools differ in their opinion regarding 'anything from the sea'. It is well within scope if someone is going to be using your answer as a basis for what they eat/don't eat which may be against the school of thought this individual follows

Answer (score -1):

First of all Every sea food is halaal.

the following is the alcohol content in mirin which is an ingredient of sushi . alcohol is prohibited, so you should avoid sushi or tell chef not to add mirin in your sushi

***There are three general types of mirin. The first is hon mirin (literally: true mirin), which contains approximately 14% alcohol and is produced by a forty- to sixty-day mashing (saccharification) process. The second is shio mirin, which contains alcohol as low as 1.5% to avoid alcohol tax. The third is shin mirin (literally: new mirin), or mirin-fu chomiryo (literally: mirin-like seasoning), which contains less than 1% alcohol yet retains the same flavor.***---- source wikipedia

Answer (score -1):

Due to almost certain cross contamination with haram things sushi is technically haram,it's probably contaminated so it is haram ,the sauces like soy sauce are haram too for they contain alchohol. But then again since I base my theory on assumptions then again technically while traveling, for benefit of muslemin,and for maintaining good manners, sushi could be just a little makrooh and not really haram ,also it is probably safe to eat from health point of view in Japan

Answer (score -3):

I have just understood that when Japanese make sushi, the rice making is also using vinegar, salt, etc.. and for the vinegar, not all vinegar can be consumed because sometimes it contains alcohol.. So, I don't know whether common sushi restaurants use edible vinegar or not.. Wallahualam..

Answer (score -3):

The crabs are not halaal. You can eat salmon with no problem. Check the rice as they habe mentioned before

Comment: Consider adding evidences supporting your claims and read [answer].