# Can non halal food become halal food

Tags: halal-haram, food

Is there a process that can turn non halal food in to halal food such as praying or cleaning/cooking the food in a certain way?

Comment: How would you turn pork into something else? Even alcohol can't be turned in something halal by any means as it seems. Please consider elaborating and making clear what you mean, do you have any example?

Comment: The other way around is possible like grapes, dates etc.

Comment: @Yas See for example [Do any schools consider eel haram and why?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5736/do-any-schools-consider-eel-haram-and-why)

Answer (score 2):

No it can not.

Haram foods have been called filth (**رجس**) in [6:145](https://quran.com/6/145?translations=84) and [5:90](https://quran.com/5/90?translations=84) and their ritual impurity is of an *inherent* nature (**نجس العين**). Nothing can be done to them to purify them. And it is not permitted to derive any benefit from them unless it is explicitly proven to be permitted.

We know that the Prophet commanded people to throw away haram foods (for example see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/72/23) , [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/22/83) and [here](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/229)) and if it was possible to make them halal by some ritual or process, then the Prophet would have commanded that instead since wastefulness is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

According to Hanafi school, if you completely burn najis substance it becomes non-najis after that complete chemical transformation, see e. g. excrements.

Comment: And what's the benefit of burning food in that case?

Comment: The conversion of bones to gelatin can serve as an instructive example. One should notice that you cannot be entirely sure some residues are remaining though.

Answer (score 0):

Non halal food cannot become halal. It is however allowed to consume non halal under starvation only but non halal will still remains non halal. Such consumption of non halal due to starvation will be forgiven by Allah as long as starvation is not self induced by laziness or day dreaming of big job.

Answer (score -1):

Allah specified some food as haram.we can't eat food which is haram. Alcohol is haram. And some food which mentioned haram in hadith and Quran as haram we can't make it halal.  Prophets diet is sunnah and You can watch this SUNNAH FOOD here ◆◆◆

https://youtu.be/BPzFi6zM4Ew