# Can Muslim Eat Sea Lobster?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, food, muslim-practices

I am a Muslim and now living in China. Today My Chinese friend invite to eat lobster. They bought two types lobster. One is so big and they say it is from the sea. And another little from the pond or like this. I know little lobster can't eat. 
But I want to know can Muslim eat sea lobster? 
I see some group they Muslim can eat sea food. Because it is not dirty.

Comment: Doesn't [Which foods from the sea are halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/which-foods-from-the-sea-are-halal) or [Lobsters and crabs halal or haram due to boiling alive?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5743/lobsters-and-crabs-halal-or-haram-due-to-boiling-alive)answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference of opinion between the madhāhib whether lobster is halal or haram. The opinion of the Hanafi madhab is that it is haram while the opinion of the other three (Hanbali, Maliki, Shafi'i) is that it is halal.

Sources: [Hanafi](https://seekersguidance.org/answers/hanafi-fiqh/is-lobster-permissible-according-to-the-hanafi-school/), [Shafi'i](https://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33412)

Comment: That is the thing. I feel confused. Some hadith say pork and lobster are dirty that's why Muslim can't eat. But sea lobster is not dirty because sea is clear.

Comment: Like I said, the Hanafi madhab doesn't permit consuming lobster while the other madhahib do. I'm not aware of any hadith concerning lobsters, or else it wouldn't have been a matter of difference of opinion.